# Importing 70MB csv file taking around 70 hours in mysql?

Tags: mysql, import, phpmyadmin, large-files

I am trying to import a csv file (space separated if that makes any difference) of 70MB
which consists of about 6 million lines , each line contains 2 numbers (2 columns).

It is taking approximately 1 hour to import 1 MB of file, which has around million lines.
I tried using the Import feature of phpmyadmin (CSV), and also tried using Bigdump but both are almost taking the same time.

My worry is how can a simple 70 MB file take such a long time (2 and half days) to load into a database? then, what is the point of using a database if importing itself takes so long ?

I put the max_memory_size = 1280 MB, so I don't think there is any memory problem for a 70mb file. I am doing it on my localhost, I also tried on my department's server. it is taking the same amount of time even when using bigdump.php and there are no internet speed problems

Comment: The prefix `m` denotes `milli` or 10^-3, please use `M` for `mega`. Also `b` denotes `bits`, please use `B` for `bytes`. Currently you are talking about millibits...

Comment: phpMyAdmin is very slow. Use the command line instead. Here's a tutorial http://chriseiffel.com/everything-linux/how-to-import-a-large-csv-file-to-mysql/

Comment: This is indeed much too slow. I frequently import multi-GB data files into MySQL in minutes. You probably are using either very slow disks, or insufficient MySQL buffer and log sizes, or both. MySQL requires some change to configuration settings. See http://www.percona.com/blog/2014/01/28/10-mysql-settings-to-tune-after-installation/ or http://www.tocker.ca/2013/09/17/what-to-tune-in-mysql-56-after-installation.html

Comment: What is actually taking the time: the insert in to the database itself or the overall time uploading the stuff? Keep in mind, that the file first needs to be uploaded entirely, which may take its time on a usual async DSL with 500Kbits upload speed.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16809/why-is-load-data-infile-faster-than-normal-insert-statements

Comment: @BillKarwin Sir, could you please suggest buffer and log configuration settings for my case. I wanna import 2.5 GB csv file on a Core 2 Duo processor with 4 GBs of RAM. For now, I am trying mysqlimport command line tool with default configuration settings and its talking took long. Thanks!!

Comment: @VikasGautam, I suggest you ask a new question on https://dba.stackexchange.com. Posing a new question in a comment is not the best way to use Stack Overflow. For your case, I would check to make sure you're not swapping.

Comment: @BillKarwin Sir, Actually my problem was same as the OP and your comment seemed to have a hidden answer. That's why I used comments. However, I have solved my problem and your comment has helped a lot. I increased the buffer size to 2G and importing is fast now. Here is a command while you're in mysql prompt:-
`mysql> SET GLOBAL innodb_buffer_pool_size=2147483648;`

Answer (score 3):

Bulk inserts can be made more efficient by disabling certain checks, and using LOAD DATA which is significantly faster at importing; eg

```
SET autocommit=0;
SET unique_checks=1;
SET foreign_key_checks=0;

  LOAD DATA INFILE myfile.txt ESCAPED BY ' '
  INTO TABLE mytable

SET unique_checks=1;o
SET foreign_key_checks=1;
COMMIT
```

More information can be found;

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html

The fact that it's taking so long may require you to investigate potential problems.

- Create an empty MyISAM table and import that data into this? Was this significantly faster? If so, You may have a sub optimal configured innodb database.
- Check the performance of doing on INSERT INTO FROM SELECT query using the MyISAM table, make sure to disable text, if this is still slow then you almost certainly have disk io issues.